# What does a white diagonal line mean on an Airbus ECAM DU?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems, avionics, airbus-a320

When my A321 powers up, the lower ECAM DU shows only a diagonal white line. What does it mean and what would be the fix?

Comment: You have a 321, but lost the POH? And don't have a service contract?

Comment: Seriously? If you're a licensed engineer you'd already be consulting Airbus's approved service manuals or the Airbus service team. If you're not a licensed engineer you ask someone who is. A stranger on the internet might tell you to hit it with a hammer. Would you do that? (Hint: don't!)

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting this question down: it's clear and presumably there's some sort of answer to it. Saying that "you should be able to answer this yourself" isn't particularly helpful. As for the 'don't trust what strangers on the internet say' comment, that's perfectly true but you could say the same thing about every question on this site :-)

Comment: I never could understand why people downvote a question when the OP has a rep of 1. It seems kinda pointless, sort of in the same vein as beating a dead horse.

Comment: @Pondlife The answer is to simply follow the procedure in the A320 TSM, which the OP hasn't provided any evidence of following, or even knowledge thereof. It isn't a useful question to anybody to post a list of AMM procedures for every random aircraft fault.

Comment: @pondlife The problem with Stack Exchange engaging with this sort of maintenance question is that it's a safety issue. There will be an approved procedure documented for this particular aircraft that might differ from an apparently very similar aircraft operated by another airline. Getting it wrong could be seriously damaging to the health of hundreds of people. I wouldn't want to fly with an airline whose principle source of maintenance information is 'some bloke on the internet'.

Comment: @user71659 Sure, and IMO this is one of many grey areas that we have on this site, which is normal. Is it a useful question or not? Is it a safe question or not? I don't know the answers to those, but I don't like closing a question only because we 'disapprove' of it. Anyway, I'm just one person with an opinion and this is why we have votes :-)

Comment: @ReddHerring That's all very true, but is it our job to 'police' questions, identify ones with safety of flight aspects, and then close them? For example, we've answered lots of questions about flying technique and procedures in light GA aircraft and getting it wrong in those cases could also have serious consequences. What's the difference?

Comment: @pondlife The difference is the relationship between the person asking the question and those most affected by an error. For GA-related queries this is often the same person, who can make a judgement on whether he/she consider the answers appropriate. For airlines, those with most to lose are the passengers, whose safety depends on the integrity of the certification and licensing system. One 'engineer' with a cavalier approach to proper procedure can wreak havoc. 'Some bloke on the internet' doesn't have a place here and we should not enable it. This might be a good question for Meta.

Comment: The question likely comes from someone using a serious game simulator, it seems such questions are downvoted and closed with a vengeance by some of us. So just ignore them and upvote...

Comment: @ReddHerring Personally, I don't like making assumptions about the background to questions. mins has a great point that this could be a sim, for example. Or it's a question from some kind of maintenance written test that the person doesn't understand. There are lots of plausible possibilities that don't involve putting real people at risk. But it could indeed be a good meta question and if you want to discuss it then don't hesitate to ask it there!

Comment: Thanks to all that responded. As for Redd Herring or whoever this superior engineer is, why be negative?  It’s a valid question and I guess when you work on aircraft you have a laptop by your side to access the maintenance manuals at all times?  I did not and have only been an engineer for 48 years. I subscribe to the philosophy that there are NO STUPID QUESTIONS.

Answer (score 4):

Display Management Computer issue:

> If a DMC fails, all information is removed from the displays it
>   controls and replaced by a white diagonal line to indicate a working
>   display with a failed source. ECAM will detect the failure and provide
>   a sequence of alerts.
>
> Due to the priority rules, the E/WD display will
>   move to the lower DU if it was DMC1 that failed. The EIS DMC switch is
>   used to replace the failed DMC with DMC3.

[Source](https://hursts.org.uk/airbus-technical/html/ar01s20.html#idm45838557924064)

---

Steps to clear warning:

> First select DMC #3 to isolate fault to DU or DMC. If DMC is at fault
>   reset above associated circuit breaker for 5 seconds. If fault is with
>   DU reset these (CAPT PFD/ND = G3/E1) (FO's PFD/ND = R3/R4) (Upper ECAM
>   = E5) (Lower ECAM = R11).

[Source](http://mobile.airlinetechs.com/airbus/31/31blankscreens.html)

---

More in the maintenance manual at AMM31-60-00-710-001. (EIS start).